# Unity + GoogleVR / Daydream: CommandInvokationFailure Build Failure

Tags: google-vr

I am unable to get the GoogleVRForUnity.unitypackage project to build using either Unity 5.3.2 or Unity 5.4.0b21. When I try to build, I get an error saying:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.

(more detail below)

The steps that I followed were 1) Create a new project 2) import the unitypackage 3) switch to Android 4) change the bundle identifier & orientation 5) build  (as outlined here: https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/get-started-controller#import_and_preview_the_demo_scene)

I am using:

- The latest from github (https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk v0.8.1)
- jdk1.8.0_91
- Up to date Android Studio installed (2.1)
- Android 6.X (N) API 24 Rev 1 SDK installed

The error that I get is this:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
>   C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Robert/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.google.vr.cardboard:vr.gvr.platform.unity -S "C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res" -S "C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unitygvractivity\res"
>
> stderr[
>
> ]
>   stdout[
>   Configurations:
>    (default)
>
> Files:
>     AndroidManifest.xml
>       Src: () AndroidManifest.xml
>
> Resource Dirs:
>   Including resources from package: C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar
>   applyFileOverlay for drawable
>   trying overlaySet Key=ic_settings_48dp.png
>   trying overlaySet Key=quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png
>   trying overlaySet Key=quantum_ic_arrow_downward_white_24.png
>   trying overlaySet Key=quantum_ic_arrow_upward_white_24.png
>   trying overlaySet Key=quantum_ic_settings_white_24.png
>   trying overlaySet Key=rippleable.xml
>   trying overlaySet Key=transition.png
>   trying overlaySet Key=app_banner.png
>   trying overlaySet Key=app_icon.png
>   applyFileOverlay for layout
>   trying overlaySet Key=back_button.xml
>   trying overlaySet Key=transition_view.xml
>   trying overlaySet Key=ui_layer.xml
>   trying overlaySet Key=ui_layer_with_portrait_support.xml
>   applyFileOverlay for anim
>   applyFileOverlay for animator
>   applyFileOverlay for interpolator
>   applyFileOverlay for transition
>   applyFileOverlay for xml
>   applyFileOverlay for raw
>   applyFileOverlay for color
>   applyFileOverlay for menu
>   applyFileOverlay for mipmap
>   Processing image: res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
>   Processing image: res\drawable\app_icon.png
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable\ic_settings_48dp.png
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png: 154% size of source)
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png: 138% size of source)
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png: 129% size of source)
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable\ic_settings_48dp.png: 172% size of source)
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png: 136% size of source)
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-ldrtl-mdpi-v17\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-ldrtl-mdpi-v17\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png: 152% size of source)
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png: 113% size of source)
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png: 140% size of source)
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png: 122% size of source)
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png: 133% size of source)
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_downward_white_24.png
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17\quantum_ic_arrow_back_white_24.png: 109% size of source)
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_downward_white_24.png: 146% size of source)
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_downward_white_24.png
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_downward_white_24.png
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_downward_white_24.png: 142% size of source)
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_downward_white_24.png
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_downward_white_24.png: 147% size of source)
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_downward_white_24.png
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_downward_white_24.png: 135% size of source)
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_upward_white_24.png
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_upward_white_24.png: 130% size of source)
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_upward_white_24.png
>       (processed image C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\quantum_ic_arrow_upward_white_24.png: 141% size of source)
>   Processing image: C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\DaydreamTest\Test2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr_android_common\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\quan
>   ]
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.CompileResources (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android Studio, SDK Manager. Remove the Android Build tool.
Then, start your Unity and build the apps. It would ask you to update the Android SDK. Then click "Yes". It should works after